# Retrieve array key passed on value PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have the following array

```
$group= array(
    [0] => 'apple',
    [1] => 'orange',
    [2] => 'gorilla'
);
```

I run the array group through an for each function and when the loop hits values of gorilla I want it to spit out the index of gorilla

```
foreach ($group as $key) {

    if ($key == gorilla){
        echo   //<------ the index of gorilla
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)** function to get the key for specified value:

```
$key = array_search('gorilla', $group);
```

Comment: @Pekka: You forgot about it but you had provided this function for a question few days back :)

Comment: yup, I was focused on the "how to get the current key in the loop" aspect :)

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach( $group as $index => $value) {

if ($value == "gorilla")
 {
  echo "The index is: $index";
 }

}
```

Comment: Though this is correct, I think use of the word 'key' is definitely wrong here. Indexes don't link to keys, they link to values ..

Comment: @Matt totally, I just copied the variable name without thinking. Corrected, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

[array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) — Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($group as $key => $value) {
    if ($value=='gorilla') {
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

The `foreach($c as $k => $v)` syntax is similar to the `foreach($c as $v)` syntax, but it puts the corresponding keys/indices in `$k` (or whatever variable is placed there) for each value `$v` in the collection.

However, if you're just looking for the index of a single value, [`array_search()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) may be simpler. If you're looking for indices for many values, stick with the `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($group as $key => $value)
{
    echo "$key points to $value";
}
```

[foreach documentation on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)